# Connect Firebase database to webapp using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I need some help with my website. I'm stuck on connecting the Firebase database to the site. I would like the information from the database to be displayed after "Length", "Director" etc.  This is my code on my website:

```
<!doctype html>


<html>

<head> 
    <title>Movie title</title>
    </head>

<body>

    <div>
    <img src="bilder/james.jpg" height="300"/>
    </div>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.1/firebase.js">     </script>
<script>
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyC7UjgICAi58ZytqsMVMqQshXgd3lxsVEw",
    authDomain: "test-62cdd.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://test-62cdd.firebaseio.com",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

    <script src="index.js"></script>

         Length: 
         Direcor: 
         Actors: 

    </body>


</html>
```

I also have an index.js file:

```
var langd = document.getElementById("Length");

var langdref = firebase.database().ref().child("Length");

langdref.on("value", function(datasnapshot){

    langd.innertext = datasnapshot.val();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with there is no element with the id "Length" in your html.  Check the developer tools for your browser to get more info.  If that's taken care of have a look at the "Read data once" section of the link below for help getting the data out of the db.  I have made copious use of console.log() while getting familiar with Firebase.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: How can I add an id in my html? (Im a total beginner in programming). I will look up the info in the link. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can add id in your html:
eg:

```
<a href="" id="length">my link
</a>
```

After doing so your javascript code will be able to manipulate this element binding through id.
Here is a quick example of what i did in my code:

```
var mainEmail= document.getElementById("email");

<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
```